# Eager Load Matrix Field with Assets Field Type

Tags: matrix, eager-loading

I am trying to eager load an image asset assigned to a matrix. The template is pulling entries in from a section and each entry has the matrix field assigned to it that serves as an image gallery.

The error I am getting back using the syntax below is
**Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "primaryImage".**

Section Handle: products

Matrix Field Handle: gallery

Block Type Handle: productImages

Field Handle: primaryImage, Field Type: Assets

```
 {% set products = craft.entries({
     section: 'products',
         with:[
                    ['gallery.productImages:primaryImage', {
                      withTransforms: [
                      'heroImage'
                    ]
              }],
          ] 
  }) %}
```

Template Code:

```
 {% for entry in products %}
      {% for block in entry.gallery %}
            {% if block.type == 'productImages' %}
                 {% set img = entry.primaryImage[0] ?? null %}
                       {% if img %}
                            <img src="{{ img.url('heroImage') }}">
                       {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the `primaryImage` asset field definitely in the products section field layout?

Comment: Yes it's an assets field that belongs to the productImages block type in the gallery Matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `{% set img = entry.primaryImage[0] ?? null %}` is looking for the `primaryImage` field on the `entry` inside your `for` loop. It is not looking for `primaryImage` for the current matrix field.

If `primaryImage` is a field within your matrix blog you will need to change the line to

`{% set img = block.primaryImage[0] ?? null %}`